# Dynamic Crypto Map with IPv6 access list

Tags: cisco, ipv6, ipsec

I am trying to configure a dynamic crypto map for use on a pure IPv6 network, on Cisco 15.2M. The problem is when I try to add an ipv6 access list to the dynamic crypto map, I get an error message. Below the config

```
crypto dynamic-map DYNMAP 5
 set transform-set IPSECVPN-PeerA
 set ikev2-profile IKEV2-SETUP-DYN
ipv6 access-list VPN_PEER_A_IPV6_ANY
 permit ipv6 2001:1::/64 any
 permit ipv6 2001:2::/64 any
```

But when I try to add the access list to the crypto map, I get the following error

```
access-list type conflicts with prior definitionERROR: "VPN_PEER_A_IPV6_ANY" is either an invalid name or the
    list already exists but is the wrong type.
```

I believe this is due to 15.2 not supporting dynamic IPv6 crypto maps. Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, [Dynamic Crypto Maps with IPv6 are NOT SUPPORTED by Cisco IOS 15.2](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_conn_vpnips/configuration/15-2mt/sec-cfg-vpn-ipsec.html#GUID-E60D2A18-9162-47EE-BE21-CDCDB82259E9)